# Laravel, reducir rutas en vistas usando blade

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, blade

Me encuentro realizando un proyecto en el cual tengo en la plantilla maestra tengo un Select de registros traídos desde una base de datos. 
He buscado y no encuentro como el siguiente extracto del código reducir para que tome todas las rutas y subrutas de categorias... Pensaba en algo como /categorias/* pero no funciona.

```
@if(!(Request::url()==url('/drivers') OR Request::url()==url('/categorias') OR Request::url()==url('/categorias/index') OR Request::url()==url('/categorias/create')))
```

Answer (score 1):

No hace falta el helper `url()` en la comparación, con tan solo poner

```
@if (\Request::is('categorias/*')) { 
   //Incluira todas la ruta con sus subcategorias.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Si la idea es reducir la cantidad de comprobaciones del if, se podría hacer algo así con el helper `str_contains`:

```
@if (str_contains(Request::url(), ['categorias', 'drivers']))
```

Aunque depende hasta que punto se desea que siempre tenga el texto categorias o drivers.

Más información: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/helpers#method-str-contains