# Laravel!! Reducción de rutas url('/cateogiras/{{any}}'?

Tags: php, html, laravel, bootstrap, laravel-blade

Tengo esta ruta en `web.php`

```
Route::get('/categorias/index/{cat_id}/{ruta_id}','CategoriasController@searchByCat');
```

Y al recibirla en la vista `categorias.index` quiero generar una verificación en caso de que tenga o no id anexado

Algo así

```
@if(!(Request::url()==url('/drivers') OR Request::url()==url('/categorias') OR Request::url()==url('/') OR Request::url()==url('/categorias/index') OR Request::url()==url('/categorias/create')))
```

Quiero resumir a

`url('/categorias/*') {{--Para que se reduzca a todas las extenciones de categorias--}}`

Pero por mas que busco no he logrado dar con la solución. He probado un par de cosas como  `url('/categorias/{{anny}}')` y me arroja errores de variables

Comment: Qué coincidencia, otro usuario con el mismo nombre ya hizo esa misma pregunta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/230093/laravel-reducir-rutas-en-vistas-usando-blade/230096#230096

Comment: Problemas con la cuenta, sigo con esta y respondo por si a alguien mas le sirve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Termine por solucionarlo de la siguiente forma, utilizando Blade

```
@if (\Request::is('categorias/*') OR \Request::is('drivers/*') OR \Request::is('archivos/create/*') OR \Request::is('archivos/services/index/*'))
```

Asi, solo se ejecutara lo que este dentro del if si se encuentra en alguna de esas rutas o sus subrutas